# Appcelerator / Titanium - Is this way of saving models from a JSON response too memory intensive?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In my app I'm pulling in a JSON structure using `Ti.Network.createHTTPClient` and then looping through the objects and saving each one as a new model. Is this an inefficient way of doing it? I'm new Titanium and Alloy so I'm not sure of best practices. Is there a better way of achieving this?

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

        var repsonseJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // parse response as JSON object

        // loop through the data and create/save a model for each one
        _.each(repsonseJSON.brands, function (i) {
            var brand = Alloy.createModel('brands', i);
            theBrands.add(brand);
            brand.save();
        });

        _.each(repsonseJSON.videos, function (i) {
            var video = Alloy.createModel('videos', i);
            theVideos.add(video);
            video.save();
        });

        if (callback) callback(); // callback used to open app in init function
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        console.log('Error while loading data', e.error);
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
xhr.open("GET", this.data_url); // open the request
xhr.send();  // request is actually sent with this statement
```

Comment: this is more of a backbone specific question than a titanium question, however without writing or modifying your sync adapter this is the best solution